# Release configuration missing

Tags: configuration

I have an application that was originally written in an older version of visual studio and now converted to visual studio 2022.  Everything seems to work ok.  However, I am missing the release version form the configuration manager.  The debug configuration is the only selection available.  The question is how do I create a Release version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the configurations are not missing. It is only stored within the programName.exe file. I have the same problem. I think this is a bug.
The solution is to first change Debug mode and Rebuilt solution. Copy the created configuration file to Release folder.